Picking orientation of three vectors to minimize volume.
Assume you have three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ Then they form an infinity pyramid with its apex at the origin (if we consider the lines spanned by the vectors).
This partitions the space into two volumes. The "inside" of the pyramid and the "outside", each corresponding to a choice of orientation, given by the order in which we enumerate our vectors.
In $\mathbb{R}^2$ with two vectors, we could figure out which order gives the smaller angle by grabbing the signed angle of $v_1, v_2$ and $v_2, v_1$ and grabbing the smaller one. So in the image, this is the difference between picking the small wedge $ABC$ vs the large "cut pizza" $ACB$.
What test can I do in the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case to find out which of the two orientations of my vectors will produce the smaller pyramid?


I think this question is based on a misconception. In 2D we have clockwise angles and counterclockwise angles. The vectors listed in either order will give you one large angle and one small angle; the only difference is whether the small angle is clockwise or counterclockwise. If we measure clockwise angles with negative numbers then the order of vectors determines the sign of the angle between them, not the magnitude. Likewise in 3D the ordering of vectors determines the sign of the solid angle between them.

Unless the three vectors all lie in one plane, the "lines spanned by the vectors" fill all of the three-dimensional space. I think you're looking for a word that is not "span". Perhaps you mean linear combinations with non-negative coefficients, but then the "inside" and "outside" are the same regardless of the order in which you list the vectors.

It sounds like what you want is to list the three vectors in a sequence that gives a positive triple scalar product. To do this, choose a sequence, compute the triple product, and if it's negative, swap two vectors. Done!

There is no miss conception. In 2D the two vectors partition the space in two regions. One region is an open cone with a small angle, and the other region is its complement.
The exact same thing happens in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you have two sets of points, one corresponding to the "small" pyramidal cone, and the other to the complement.
Each pair-wise subset of the 3 vectors describes a plane. Depending on the order, their normal points "inside" or "outside". Thus the question is how to pick the orientation that always has them pointing out.

What did not make sense to me was calling one signed angle "smaller" than the other when they are the same magnitude but opposite signs, and the notion that the 2D case would explain the 3D case directly. If you mean to define "inside" and "outside" the cone by assigning a normal vector to each of its flat surfaces, you may certainly do so, but that should have been the problem statement. You can get that kind of orientation by computing the triple product as I described, then take the vectors in cyclic order to determine the orientation of each face.
